# How do I use this LED strip?

Tags: arduino, led, led-strip

I got this LED strip that I'm trying to control with my arduino. I searched for similar strips online but couldn't find any. I only has leads for DIN (blue), GND (black, splits in 2), and +5V (red). I couldn't find the data sheet and the part number didn't generate any results when I Google searched it. All i really need to know is the name of this type of LED strip so I can continue to research how to control it, but if there are any tutorials out there that use this type of strip, a link would be much appreciated.

[image: led strip end]
[image: led strip connectors]
[image: led strip]

Comment: Its hard to see whats actually in there from those photos. All I see is what looks like an RGB led(?) and a limitting resistor(??). Isn't there a control chip in each segment? Try searching on the chip number if so. Pololu sells led strips and HobbyKing has a few different types (without much additional info though, Im afraid).

Comment: @Octopus you will get the rep one day, just right a few serious answers and you can make comments in no time. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks similar to this LED strip: http://www.adafruit.com/products/1138

According to the [code linked from that page](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NeoPixel), it's controlled by a weird protocol used by the [Worldsemi WS2811](http://www.world-semi.com/en/Driver/Lighting_LED_driver_chip/WS2811/) LED driver chips on the strip: 24 bits for each RGB LED, 800 or 400 kHz data rate, 50 microsecond pause to latch the data. There is a pulse for each bit, 0 bits are a short pulse, and 1 bits are a long pulse.

Comment: You are my hero.

Comment: Without any codes or information, it's hard to tell if this is correct. It does look similar, probably a 30 led per meter version of the Adafruit one, but WS2811 or similar protocol is hardly the only led strip that uses only three pins.

Comment: This is the one. I got it working.